# Implementing HTTPS Server and Client in JAVA

Tags: java, ssl, https

I would like to implement a Two-Way SSL handshake in java without using any API's. I wish to implement using native `ServerSocket` and `Socket` classes in java.

During SSL handshake between server and client, I want to read each certificate in certificate  chain and verify myself whether it is valid or not .

How to implement this in Java. I tried goggling for hours all I got was these links. I dont know to implement SSL handshake part. Can anybody please guide me ?

Links I found :

[Oracle Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/security/SSL_client.html#wp1029656)

[Stack Overflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308479/simple-java-https-server)

[Blog Link](http://jcalcote.wordpress.com/2009/06/18/java-https-client-issues/)

Comment: "Without using any API's?"  What exactly does that mean?

Comment: without using com.sun.net.httpsserver class

Comment: Too broad. Forget it. It's too hard. It took them three releases of JSSE to get it right before it was incorporated into the JDK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051989/a-java-http-server